# Where to initialize data needed for execution of method

Tags: ruby, oop, design-patterns

I have a class that build some data and generator objects. Method *generate* delegates execution to generators objects. What is the best way to initialize generators and data needed for generation. I see two alternatives:

Initialize data in readers:

```
class SomeClass
  def generate
    generators.each(&:generate)
  end

  def generators
    @generators ||= some_data.map do |data|
      generator_class.new(data)
    end
  end

  def some_data
    @some_data ||= # initialize some not trival data
  end

  def generator_class
    @generator_class ||= # finding generator class
  end
end
```

or load everything in generate method:

```
class SomeClass
  def generate
    generator_class = find_generator_class
    some_data = initialize_some_data

    generators ||= some_data.map do |data|
      generator_class.new(data)
    end

    generators.each(&:generate)
  end

  def initialize_some_data
  end

  def find_generator_class
  end
end
```

Which one looks better? Maybe there is another way to do something like that?

Comment: Do you have access to this data at the moment of instantiation of the class?

Comment: Yes, but i need to process them first, which I do in method initialize_some_data

Comment: Lazy initializers are only really useful if they might *not* be called. If they're always going to be called there's really little difference here.

Comment: I do the second method posted. It is very useful when you have a lot of code in `controller` and may want to use it in different `def` (assume that you may need it more than once)